# Better Redesign of a pop-up with too many checkbox options

Tags: checkboxes, popup, many-options

[image]
Hello, I want to redesign this pop-up which has 56 choices of features provided by hotels, and I need to insert all of them. I cannot filter them because there are really different things over there and the categorization will not have a point. The only thing I thought to improve scanability is to put an index for each letter (since it is in an alphabetical order) and make the pop up bigger to have more options to show. Are there any other thoughts of how I can improve it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think an alphabetical index will be very effective. While the option is `BBQ Grill`, I might be looking under G for `Grill`, or `Restroom` instead of `Bathroom`. Could you categorize them at all? Even some broad categories might greatly help.

Comment: *there are really different things over there and the categorization will not have a point* . How is that? At first sight it looks like categorization is the perfect approach for this, so not sure if there's something else we don't know. If so, please explain this since it's very important for the answer

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution is to categorize the features. You could differentiate them by their destination, so for example:

**Bathroom**

- Bathtub
- Shower
- Hydromasage
- Hairdryer
- Towels
- Toilet

**Recreation**

- Masage
- Fitness
- SPA
- Swimming pool

Also I would try to put them in columns (3 or even 4) - It should look way better than scrolling through a modal window, and the user could see everything at once. On the other hand, if you want to stick to one column, you could display it as an accordion, making category titles a toggle link to show the requested features.

Comment: I agree that section labels are great, but note the OP's disclaimer: "_categorization will not have a point_"

Comment: Yes, I saw this remark, but as far as I see these are hotel features. I'm pretty sure there is a point in putting them into categories.

Comment: Yes,you may be right. I will do a categorization with 12 categories (1.Main Feautures, 2.Spaces, 3.Check in, 4.Children, 5.Pets, 6.Parking, 7.Hotel Sevices, 8.Private Services, 9.Equipment, 10.Tours,  11.Recreation, 12.Others!) Thank you for helping me and give me a very good idea of categorization :)! That was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

First show the 10 most commonly used option as a guide for new users who need ideas, then sort by category after that so it's easy to browse by area of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that an alphabetical list isn't useful unless the user knows exactly what something will be called, e.g. a list of countries or vegetables  (and even so there are ambiguities - aubergine / eggplant).

Perhaps the OP can elaborate on why categorisation isn't an option, because it seems an obvious solution to me. You could also repeat some options under different categories (not done excessively), e.g. Family / Baby sitting and Convenience / Baby sitting. This caters for different mental models. Try some card sorting exercises to understand how people group these features.

OP, have you looked at competitor sites to see how they do this? Patterns used on high traffic travel sites may not be the best but have the advantage of being familiar.

I think a combination of all the suggestions given here (search / categories / surfacing the most popular / better layout) will give you a better solution. Test and iterate!

Answer (score 0):

## Filter as you type

Better than an alphabetic index, let users type in what they're after. At first, they may have to scroll around to see what's available. But after a few times through the list they'll have an idea of what's available.

[image: Select list with search filter]

Comment: I will definitely do that with my categorization. They are going to see this list only once in the set up. But I think it may be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Consider having another look at categorisation, I think that you will find that it will help. I note that you have said categorisation is pointless, but is that because you feel the choices are so varied?

If that is the case, I think you'll find that you can start to form some pretty broad categories, things like 'Room Amenities', 'Hotel Amenities', 'Hotel Services', etc. If something doesn't fit, or is on its own, then use a general or 'miscellaneous' category.

As an example I'll list a few things:

**Room Amenities**

Hair Dryer, Air Conditioning, TV etc

**Hotel Amenities**

Pool, Elevators, Creche etc

**Hotel Services**

Laundry, Concierge, Valet Parking etc

I'm not telling you that these are the best categories, but I am saying that I think with some thought that categorisation could be the way to go. Unless of course you have a different reason as to why this won't work. If something fits in more than one category, then consider putting it in both categories, that shouldn't be a problem.

You could alphabetise each category, but for a long single list of 56 I don't think this will work, for the reasons mentioned in some of the other comments. For shorter lists this is more just to add some organisation to the lists and to 'assist' in finding a choice, but shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: Your categorization is very helpful and I will use it creating 12 categories (1.Main Feautures, 2.Spaces, 3.Check in, 4.Children, 5.Pets, 6.Parking, 7.Hotel Sevices, 8.Private Services, 9.Equipment, 10.Tours,  11.Recreation, 12.Others!) Thank you for helping me and give me a very good idea of categorization :)! That was really helpful

Comment: Thanks @EvaSoroniati, happy to help. If it did help, it would be great if you could up vote this answer.